# Unity: Increase transition smoothness

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an android game with a pendulum in it, the motion of the pendulum when in unity play mode is smooth but in phone the transition lags and is not smooth.Below is the code i use.

```
float angle = 35;
public float speed;
Quaternion qStart, qEnd;


void Start () {
    qStart = Quaternion.AngleAxis ( angle, Vector3.forward);
    qEnd   = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, Vector3.forward);
    speed = 1.5f;   
}

void Update () {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (qStart, qEnd, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);

    if(Time.timeScale == 0)
        transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);


}
```

Comment: Tried activating Vsync? Edit->Project settings->Quality
Change the "V Sync count" and see if the result improves.

Comment: results were the same

Comment: I don't know this is the reason but **do not use `Time.time`**. Use `Time.deltaTime` with high `speed` instead.

Comment: i tried using Time.deltaTime the it wasn't rotating

Comment: Did you consider increasing `speed = 1.5f;` to something like `speed = 150f;` or higher?